# Should a chapter title be punctuated with quotes in text?

Tags: punctuation

If one is typing the name of the chapter inside a story, do they put quotes around it? If not,  how is one indicated?

Comment: Have you checked any style guides on this? Do they have anything to say about in-text citations?

Comment: This is entirely a style issue. It could be in quotes, italics, boldface, small capitals, underlined, or any combination; it could simply be set of with commas. "As we saw in Chapter 2, The Application of Style, anything is possible."

Answer (score 3):

This depends largely on your purpose for writing. For example, if you are writing a novel, fictional work, or other non-peer reviewed content, it generally becomes in issue of personal preference.

If you are writing an extended article, textbook, research paper, or something else of an academic nature, your best option would be to consult with the style guide for the specific discipline of your content.

Some common ones for reference:
APA
Turubian (Chicago)
MLA
AMA
CSA
ACS